A scheduled task using relative path to start a powershell script does not work on windows 10
I have written following createTask.bat to create a scheduled task that should run myscript.ps1 at a regular interval.
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set myloc=%~dp0myscript.ps1

C:\Windows\System32\schtasks /create /sc minute /mo 10 /ru "SYSTEM" /tn "My script" /tr "powershell.exe -File \"%myloc%\"" /F 

endlocal

After running this script the task is successfully created but it does not run myscript.ps1 as expected. It works on windows server os but not on windows 10.
On windows 10 if I give absolute path in
C:\Windows\System32\schtasks /create /sc minute /mo 10 /ru "SYSTEM" /tn "My script" /tr "powershell.exe -File \"C:\temp\myscript.ps1\"" 
it works.
But I want to use %~dp0, so the script can be relocatable to anywhere else.
What do I need to do?
